# проверка условия в bash

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть цикл, в котором проверяются введенные данные. Если данные равны пустой строки, то выход из цикла. Но никак не пойму как сделать правильную проверку на пустую строку. Вот так вот не работает:

```
while [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
do
    read n m
    if [[ n=="" || m=="" ]] # This is the mistake
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

В данном примере условие срабатывает всегда.

Comment: Вы передаете параметры?

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No arguments supplied"
fi

Comment: рекомендую посмотреть вот этот ответ: http://serverfault.com/a/382740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так должно заработать (знаки `$` перед именем переменной):

```
while true
do
    read n m
    if [[ "$n" == "" || "$m" == "" ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Кавычки вокруг `$n` и `$m` нужны на случай если переменная равна пустой строке, иначе без кавычек получилось бы `if [[  == "" ||  == "" ]]; then`

Чуть более компактный вариант:

```
while :; do
    read n m
    [[ -z $n || -z $m ]] && break
done
```

Здесь в условии `while` используется команда `:` которая ничего не делает и всегда возвращает `true`.  В качестве условия используется `-z` который проверяет строку на пустую строку.

Comment: Да, так действительно заработало. Единственное, не понятно почему обязательно пробелы нужны перед и после `==`. Без них условие выполняется всегда.

Comment: `-z $n || -z $m`

Comment: @faoxis без пробелов это сольется в один аргумент для `if`. Как если бы вы писали `cp file1file2` вместо `cp file1 file2`.

Comment: В смысле, в один аргумент ? В какой ?

Comment: @faoxis В аргумент для `if`.

Comment: @faoxis и рекомендую вариант Pink Tux (`-z $n || -z $m`) как более идеологически верный (для проверки на пустую строку).